# Difference between UserProperties.Add and UserProperties.Set functionality in FlurrySDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm using Flurry Analytics in my Unity game and I want to use Flurry UserProperties.

My question is about the difference between the functionality of `UserProperties.Add` and `UserProperties.Set` methods in FlurrySDK.

In the [documents](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/userproperties/) there is following description :

> Set :
> Sets and replaces (if any exist) the value(s) for the property.

> Add :
> Adds a User Property value(s). Adding values already included in the state has no effect and does not error.

Can I just use `Flurry.UserProperties.Add` whenever I need to set/add an UserProperty for a user and ignore `Flurry.UserProperties.Set`?

or I need to first define every property with `Flurry.UserProperties.Add` to be added in Flurry's panel and then use `Flurry.UserProperties.Set` to set them for a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add adds to existing values, while Set removes existing values and then adds the new one

Answer (score 1):

To create your custom User.property you do it in the Admin Panel of Flurry.

- Set, clean your property and set with your last value you send.
- Add , preserve the old values and add a new value to your property.